# JSON foreach not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON code:

```
{
    "chat": [
        {
            "username": "demo",
            "text": "hi man",
            "time": "1380167419"
        },
        {
            "username": "admin",
            "text": "hi",
            "time": "1380167435"
        },
        {
            "username": "demo",
            "text": "this works flawless now.",
            "time": "1380167436"
        },
        {
            "username": "demo",
            "text": "we basically done/",
            "time": "1380167443"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run:

```
var codes = JSON.parse(history); //history is the above JSON.
$.each(codes, function(key, value){
alert(value.chat.username);
});
```

It's not alerting anything and keeps telling me value.chat.username is undefined...

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Tho don't understand why those down votes...but thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time you have an array of objects defined in `value.chat`. You need to select an array element before you can look at `username`. The correct form is `value.chat[n].username`, where `n` is the index in your array. If you want to iterate through the array in your `chat` object you need to do this:

```
$.each(codes.chat, function(key, value){
  alert(value.username);
});
```

Note that we're now iterating over `chat`, so we can address the properties in each `chat` element directly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to parse the JSON. It's already a JSON object

```
$.each(history.chat, function(key, value){
alert(value.username);
});
```

You also have to iterate over the chat array and reference its items correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That's... because .chat isn't defined

```
var codes = JSON.parse(history); //history is the above JSON.
$.each(codes.chat, function(key, value){
    alert(value.username);
});
```